# Nested glob directory listings not returning properly

Tags: python, windows-7, glob, id3

I am trying to fix a decent number of Id3 Album/Artist tags in (3500+) music files spread through a directory tree structure like so:

```
"Winamp Library/Artist Name/Album Name/Song.(mp3/flac/whatever)"
```

This code only prints a list of Artist Names in the base "Winamp Library" directory, what am I doing wrong?

```
for artist in glob.glob('Winamp Library/*'):
    print(artist)
    for album in glob.glob('Winamp Library/' + artist+  '/*'):
        print (album)
```

Ouput:

```
Winamp Library\Artist 1
Winamp Library\Artist 2
```

When the output should be:

```
Winamp Library\Artist 1
Winamp Library\Artist 1\Album1
Winamp Library\Artist 1\Album2
Winamp Library\Artist 2
etc
```

Comment: You might find this task easier with `os.walk()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the glob result it will include the part of the pattern you gave as well, so you're really trying to match in the second glob:

```
'Winamp Library/Winamp Library/<ARTIST>/*'
```

I suspect you wanted something more like:

```
for artist in glob.glob('Winamp Library/*'):
    print(artist)
    for album in glob.glob(artist + '/*'):
        print (album)
```

Note that glob can do multiple levels at once, too, so you could glob on `'Winamp Library/*/*'` for example.

Comment: Of course! That works perfectly. But now what is the easiest way to store just the artist/album in a variable so I can write it to the Id3 tag?

Comment: @SamCoulter The simplest way that comes to mind is to split the string with .split() on '/'